# How to get text/value from dynamic dropdown list in Karate UI automation?

Tags: automation, karate, ui-automation

In chrome native driver in karate UI -:

1. I search for some name(example - MarketData) in dynamic dropdown
2. After typing in search box that name appears on top of dropdown list
3. Now on click of mouse or key enter I want that element to get submitted.